# PHP fatal error: Call to a member function asXML() on a non-object

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm attempting to run a php script to parse Google Calendar XML and I keep getting the following error:

> Call to a member function asXML() on a non-object in /index.php on line 120

Here's a link to my code (I've notated Line 120 - IT IS LINE 38 ON PASTEBIN) http://pastebin.com/bMHXfbkD

Anybody with any ideas / fixes would be much appreciated!

**UPDATE** @Clover and @Phil have suggested I remove the line in question, which I did, and got this:

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /Library/WebServer/Documents/index2.php on line 125

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Library/WebServer/Documents/index2.php on line 125

Comment: *"I've notated Line 120"* - where? Chances are you just haven't checked for errors in creating your `SimpleXMLElement`. See http://php.net/simplexml_load_file#refsect1-function.simplexml-load-file-errors

Comment: @Phil it is line 38 on the pastebin link. Thank you for the link I'm checking it now.

Comment: I also suggest you enable `display_errors` and set `error_reporting` to `E_ALL` for development. Line 38 (`$xml->asXML()`) wouldn't do anything even if it didn't error so I can't even see why it's there

Comment: @Phil thank you, enabled display_errors and set error_reporting to E_ALL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`simplexml_load_file` function can return FALSE, so make a test before using it.

By the way, in your case, just remove the line, it does nothing :)

Comment: thank you, I tried removing the line. I updated my question with what happened when I did that.

Comment: `if($xml !== false) { foreach($xml->entry ...) ... }`

Answer (score -2):

use try catch, and instead of using Exception class, try Throwable class

Comment: How does this relate to the question? `Throwable` only works in PHP 7, and at the time of asking this question, there was no PHP 7

Comment: @NicoHaase,

I faced this issue in php7, so responded. :)
But it works though.